why are same Python imports on Windows so slow compared to Linux? (Ubuntu)
I am building a large Python app, and once starting it from console as
python main.py

it wouldn't take too long for application to start up on my Ubuntu 22.04 OS. Everything was good, and then I moved to build same app on Windows 10 and couldn't fail to notice how it would take at least 5 seconds for the application to start, and for Ubuntu it was ~1 second. I then started investigating and found that literally every single import statement on Windows runs much slower compared to Ubuntu.
Some examples:
import time
start = time.time()
from PySide6.QtCore import * # I know import * is not the most appropriate way, I am just showing an example
print(time.time() - start)
# 0.21s on Windows, 0.12s on Ubuntu

import time
start = time.time()
import scipy.signal
print(time.time() - start)
# 0.64s on Windows, 0.17s on Ubuntu

import time
start = time.time()
from numba import njit
print(time.time() - start)
# 0.3s on Windows, 0.07s on Ubuntu

And all these differences add up in the app to the point where user opening the app starts noticing the difference. How does it happen so that everything that Windows import is so slow?

Could be Windows Defender according to this similar QnA.

Well, Windows is generally slower, with many things stepping in the way (antivirus etc.). I thought it is a well-known thing.

Accessing many small files on Windows' filesystem is slower than on Linux'. You can use WSL2 or create a dev drive.

First of all check your Python installation and project files, make sure they are excluded from antivirus scans.
Secondly run Python with the -O flag for slight optimizations like this:
python -O main.py
